# Getting error in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I got the following error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: UpdateStatus is not defined;
Bindings value: checked: status, disable: status, click: UpdateStatus

Here is my javascript code

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
// Data
var self = this;
self.days = ['2012-10-01', '2012-10-02', '2012-10-03', '2012-10-04', '2012-10-05', '2012-10-06', '2012-10-07'];
self.choosenDateId = ko.observable();
self.choosenDateGoal = ko.observable();
self.choosenGoalId = ko.observable();

self.UpdateNote = ko.computed(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateNote',
        data: "{goalId:9423}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
    });
});

self.UpdateStatus = ko.computed(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateStatus',
        data: "{goalId: 9423}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
    });
});

// Behaviours    
self.gotoDay = function (days) { location.hash = days };

// Client-side routes    
Sammy(function () {

    this.get('#:days', function () {          
        self.choosenDateId(this.params.days);

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/GetGoals',
            data: "{goalDate:'" + this.params.days + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                self.choosenDateGoal(msg.d);

                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        })
    });
    this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#2012-10-04') });
}).run();
};
```

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add html markup, please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are using computed observables in the wrong sense. If you want a function to be called(like you want, since you're binding it to a click binding) just declare it as

```
self.<function Name> = function(< passed variables>){
    //Code to be done when this function is called.
};
```

Where as computed are meant more to be used as variables. And as such, if there is only the passed function to a computed, it is treated as a read only variable. You can specify a computed to be read and writable but then you will have to provide a read and write function like:

```
self.<computed Name> = ko.computed(function(){
    read: function () {
        // return how you want this computed to be displayed.
    },
    write: function (value) {
        // How do you want this to be saved.
    },
});
```

Also, computed observables are meant to have existing observables used within the function.  That way whenever an observable that is used within a computed observable is updated, the computed function is called. See the [computed observable documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for examples and more information.